# Flutter StreamBuilder only for ListView and GridView?

Tags: flutter

Is there any case possible using StreamBuilder for other widgets other than ListView and GridView...?

Let's say ChoiceChip? Why ChoiceChip doesn't have builder?

Comment: you can use any widget inside StreamBuilder

Comment: @diegoveloper yes any widget within stream is possible. But I have a stream and want to build ChoiceChip from this stream. But there is not ChoiceChip builder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. we can use any other widget with Stream
see official [docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: bloc.allMovies,
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<ItemModel> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Text("data incoming");
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
      }
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    },
  )
```